# Why is "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Development" not working?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

An ASP.NET Core application has been created using the following commands.

`dotnet new globaljson --sdk-version 2.2.402`
`dotnet new mvc`

After writing some code and running the application, there was an error in the code. Using the command line, the application is started with `dotnet run`, and the console outputs `Hosting environment: Development`.  As seen in the image below, error messages are not printing. The error message asks to set "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" to "Development", but it is already set in both `launch.json` and `lanchSettings.json`.

[image]

What needs to be done for ASP.NET Core to output more detailed information about the error that occurred?

**.vscode/launch.json**

```
{
   "version": "0.2.0",
   "configurations": [
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2/PNoAWebApp.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "serverReadyAction": {
                "action": "openExternally",
                "pattern": "^\\s*Now listening on:\\s+(https?://\\S+)"                
            },
            "env": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            },
            "sourceFileMap": {
                "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Views"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Attach",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This probably won't help anyone else, but in my case I had added an extra space because I had copied it from Process Explorer, so it ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT was set to "Development " instead of "Development".

If you have this issue, double check that there are no extra spaces.